# JavaScript removeChild input from the dom

Tags: javascript, materialize, removechild

I'm trying to delete the form input posted onto the DOM, but the removeChild code isn't functioning, When inspecting the console I will be given an error which is: `materialize.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'M_Modal' of null at HTMLBodyElement.value (materialize.min.js:6)`

```js
// ----------------Models Materialize Framework----------------
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });


//Delete Exercises 
const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');

delExerciseBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if(e.target.className == 'delete'){
  const h6 = e.target.parentElement;
  h6.removeChild(e.target);
}
});

// Add User's To the Dom.
const addExerciseDom = document.querySelector('.exercise-dom');
const exerciseForm = document.querySelector('.exercises-form');

exerciseForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

  // Get Input Value
  const value = exerciseForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

  // Create Elements
  const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
  
  // Add Content
  h6.textContent = value;
  
  // Append To Dom
  addExerciseDom.appendChild(h6);  


});
```

Comment: Try to use querySelector instead of querySelectorAll since you have only one element with .modal class. The error is caused because the elems array in M.Modal.init is either null or has an entry that points to a null element. Try to console.log elems and see if you have the right elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Multiple Values of h6
Best to add id with each new h6
Check on weight and exercise

```js
// Materialize Initialization Of Autocomplete, Exercise.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
  var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems,{
    data: {
      "Lat Pull Down": null,
      "Lat  Down": null,
    },
    limit:2,
    minLength:1,
  });
});

// Materialize Initialization Of Box Select, Sets and Reps.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});

// Materialize Initialization Of Weights CharacterCount
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var textNeedCount = document.querySelectorAll('.weightcountercount');
  M.CharacterCounter.init(textNeedCount);
});
//need to put restrition on the number typed into the box without it submitting


// ----------------Models Materialize Framework----------------
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});


// ------------ Add Form's Inputs Onto The HomePage----------------

//-------------Exercises------------
// Delete Exercises From The Dom
const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');

delExerciseBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Remove Form Input
  const h6_e = document.getElementById('h6_exercise');
   h6_e.remove();
   // Remove Disable Btn
   disabledExersiceBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
});


// Add User's Exercises To The Dom.
const addExerciseDom = document.querySelector('.exercise-dom');
const exerciseForm = document.querySelector('.exercises-form');
const disabledExersiceBtn = document.querySelector('.disabled-exersicebtn');

exerciseForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

  // Get Input Value
  const value = exerciseForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

  // Create Elements
  // const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
  
  //for exercise
  const h6_exercise = document.createElement('h6');
  
  // Add Content
  h6_exercise.textContent = value;
  //adding id
  h6_exercise.setAttribute("id", "h6_exercise");
  // Append To Dom
  addExerciseDom.appendChild(h6_exercise);  

  //Disable Btn
  disabledExersiceBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

});

//---------------------Weight----------------------
// Delete Exercises From The Dom
const delWeightBtn = document.querySelector('.del-weight-btn');

delWeightBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Remove Form Input
  let h6_r = document.getElementById('h6_weight');
   h6_r.remove();
});

// Add User's Weight To The Dom.
const addWeightDom = document.querySelector('.weight-dom');
const weightForm = document.querySelector('.weight-form');

weightForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
 if(document.getElementById('h6_weight'))
  {
  let h6_r = document.getElementById('h6_weight');
  
  h6_r.remove();  
 }
   // Get Input Value
   const value = weightForm.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;
   const value1 = weightForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
   //console.log(value, value1);

   // Create Elements
   const h6_weight = document.createElement('h6');
  
  h6_weight.setAttribute('id','h6_weight')
   //h6.classList.add("center");// not working

   // Add Content
   h6_weight.textContent = value + " " + value1;
   
   // Append To Dom
   addWeightDom.appendChild(h6_weight);
   
   
  });



// ------------------Add Exercises Colum----------------------
//const addMoreBtn = document.getElementById("addmorebtn");
////const addColums = document.getElementById("addcolumns");


//addMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   // e.preventDefault();

   // const text = 
   // `<div class="col s4 height"></div>
   // <div class="col s2 height "></div>
   // <div class="col s2 height"></div>
   // <div class="col s2 height"></div>
   // <div class="col s2 height"></div>`
    
    //const position = "beforeend";
    //addColums.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
//});
```

Comment: I think you can make an empty h6 with id in html and can add innerHTML so that it will automatically replace the new value

Comment: Or the best thing you can do is you can click remove function when user click add button using if else you can specify if h6 is present then add new else click remove then add

Comment: I’m very thankful for all ur help!!! words can express my gratitude :) :) I will test out what you suggested above once I'm back from the shops. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for those words ,No worries if need my help message me anytime :)

Comment: would you mind posting the code for doing this? I can't figure it out :(

Comment: Done , is this you want check it

Comment: Oh ok no problem , its also easy i will do this tomorrow as its 2 am here

Comment: Hi boosmanhoy , you can make 3 different id's also this will help in removing last element , and using if else you can disable add button , you can use a counter in id like i=1 then use if (i==3) disable button and id should include that counter like reps1 , reps2 etc

Comment: Sure just deleted :D

Comment: Karangoyal.cc is my website you will find my info there

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```js
      // ----------------Models Materialize Framework----------------
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
  });


//Delete Exercises 
const delExerciseBtn = document.querySelector('.del-exercise-btn');

delExerciseBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const h6 = document.getElementsByTagName('h6')[0];
   h6.remove();
});

// Add User's To the Dom.
const addExerciseDom = document.querySelector('.exercise-dom');
const exerciseForm = document.querySelector('.exercises-form');
const disabledExersiceBtn = document.querySelector('.disabled-exersicebtn');

exerciseForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

  // Get Input Value
  const value = exerciseForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

  // Create Elements
  const h6 = document.createElement('h6');
  
  // Add Content
  h6.textContent = value;
  
  // Append To Dom
  addExerciseDom.appendChild(h6);  

  //Disable Btn
  disabledExersiceBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');


});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I've attempt what you suggested and it's not worked .https://codepen.io/bossmanhoy/pen/MWadXjo?editors=1010

Comment: Can you tell me the error or its the same one ,actually i am on mobile and due to electricity problem can't access to pc but i am sure i solved same issue with above statement

Comment: it's still showing the same error. I've posted a codepen above with the code you suggested and didn't remove the input mate.

Comment: I have updated the code sorry yesterday its not clear to me

Comment: getElementByTagName will not select all h6 getElementByTagName('h6')[0] will select only first h6 occurance in dom and [1] 2nd and so on... So you can either do it with loop or by passing an index to array dynamically , if you still not get the result you can send me the code so that i can understand better

Comment: I found your problem actually its best to add id with each h6 so that it will work fine , just wait i will show you in exercise column

Comment: Check my new answer it will fix your issue for sure and if it worked then you can like it :)